# How to get address City wise in Google auto complete?

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-maps, autocomplete

I have google auto complete address. 
I have city drop down above it. 
Once I select any city from dropdown,then I have to load only those address in to google auto complete that city selected by me. 
I research a lot to find out the solution for it.

I found that by passing country name we can load only those country address in to google auto complete. 
but if I want to do the same at city level then how can i do it?

Comment: Can you add a link for the démo/example google API you used ? Thanks

Comment: I used this https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js google api

Comment: In your select drop down, you have the lat and lng values ? Or you wanna load the form like the user use the form himself ?

Comment: I can get lat lng after city selected  by me.

Comment: You can restrict by postal code. It's not enough ? https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-component-restriction

Answer (score 1):

Based on quite a few issues on this on the Google Code Project gmaps-api-issues and Google own Places API Documentation I believe this to be a non-supported feature at this point.